# почему выдает ошибку Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, что не так сделал? 
В консоле на Live Server выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.theme__button') /* находим кнопку <div class="theme__button">Switch theme</div> по селектору .theme__button и записываем ее в переменную btn */
const theme = document.querySelector('.theme') /* находим блок <div class="theme">, в котором будет меняться тема, по селектору .theme и записываем ее в переменную theme */

theme.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light') /* устанавливаем значение 'light' по-умолчанию */

btn.addEventListener('click', () => { /* при клике на кнопку <div class="theme__button">Switch theme</div> */
  if (theme.getAttribute('data-theme') === 'light') { /* если у блока <div class="theme"> атрибут 'data-theme' строго равен значению 'light'  */
    theme.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark') /* тогда устанавливаем значение 'dark' */
  } else { /* а иначе */
    theme.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light') /* устанавливаем значение 'light' */
  }
})
```

```css
:root {
  --theme-color: #efefef;
  --primary-color: #000e29;
}
.theme {
  background: var(--theme-color);
  color: var(--primary-color);
}
.theme__button {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--theme-color);
}
[data-theme="light"] {
  --theme-color: #efefef;
  --primary-color: #000e29;
}
[data-theme="dark"] {
  --theme-color: #000e29;
  --primary-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme">
  <div class="theme__button">Switch theme</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, ничего не выдаёт

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в песочнице, все работает, я использую vs code с live server, и на страннице  выдает ошибку

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, когда вы вставляете скрипт на странице. В песочнице он запускается, когда элементы уже есть в DOM. Возможно, в вашей станице скрипт работает, когда элементов ещё нет в документе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас на странице нет элемента с классом `theme` в момент выполнения `document.querySelector('.theme')`. Заверните код в

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  ...
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло, можете объяснить что именно делает эта функция

Comment: @frayer Откладывает выполнение кода внутри `function(){...}` до окончания загрузки страницы.