# Как запоминать тему на странице?

Tags: javascript

есть такой скрипт, который запоминает тему на странице, но проблема в том, что это происходит только на индексе, а при переходе на другую страницу тема не меняется

```
if (localStorage.getItem("theme") == "light") {
  darkBtn.classList.remove("dark-btn-on");
  document.body.classList.remove("dark-theme");
} else if (localStorage.getItem("theme") == "dark") {
  darkBtn.classList.add("dark-btn-on");
  document.body.classList.add("dark-theme");
} else {
  localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
}
```

Comment: Очень плохо задан вопрос.

Comment: код проверки значит надо иметь на каждой странице,а не только в индексе

Comment: @скрипт подключен к каждой странице

Comment: @Igor почему плохо?

Answer (score 2):

Варианты:

1. На других страницах нет этого кода.
2. На других страницах нет используемых стилей.
3. Код выполняется до создания элементов (как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234534)).

Comment: кажется я понял в чем проблема, у меня при клике на кнопку добавляется стиль dark-theme, но только на одной странице

Comment: @frayer Я не понимаю, что это значит. В вопросе нет никаких кликов.